# Multiple Database Configurations in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

I need to configure 2 MongoDB databases with my Spring Boot v3.0.5 application.

I have made 2 MongoDB configurations as follows:

**RemindersConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.shourya.learn.repository")
public class RemindersConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {
    @Value("${mongodb.reminders.database}")
    private String database;

    @Bean(name = "reminders")
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        String uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/" + database;
        return MongoClients.create(uri);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }
}
```

**NotificationsConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.shourya.learn.repository")
public class NotificationsConfig extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {
    @Value("${mongodb.notifications.database}")
    private String database;

    @Bean(name = "notifications")
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        String uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/" + database;
        return MongoClients.create(uri);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return database;
    }
}
```

Repositories:

**NotificationRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface NotificationRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<NotificationModel, String> {
}
```

**ReminderRepository.java**

```
@Repository("reminderRepository")
public interface ReminderRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<ReminderModel, String> {
}
```

They run fine individually but when run together they give the following error:

> **Description:**
>
> The bean 'reminderRepository', defined in
> com.shourya.learn.repository.ReminderRepository defined in
> @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories declared on RemindersConfig, could
> not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in
> com.shourya.learn.repository.ReminderRepository defined in
> @EnableReactiveMongoRepositories declared on NotificationsConfig and
> overriding is disabled.
>
> **Action:**
>
> Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting
> spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Comment: I guess you need only one EnableReactiveMongoRepositories annotation.

Comment: ..trick (assuming/preserving the same model): you have to separate repository *packages* [1](https://www.baeldung.com/mongodb-multiple-databases-spring-data), [2](https://hasangalakdinu.medium.com/how-to-connect-multiple-mongo-db-databases-with-spring-boot-239cb464a114), ...

Comment: ... or: deactivate auto configuration & wire manually :) https://frandorado.github.io/spring/2020/12/14/spring-multiple-mongo-database.html